# Can I use Rpi 3.3V power pin (pin number 1, not GPIO signal pin) to power a 5mW green laser pointer originally powered by AAA x 2 = 3V bateries?

Tags: gpio, battery

Let's say I have a device powered by 2 AAA batteries in series (1,5v x 2 = 3v and 625 mAh).

Is it possible to replace the 2xAAA battery with the 3,3v Raspberry PI GPIO output?
Or the 0,3v may be an issue?
Also I'm afraid the GPIO amperage may fry the device.

What I want to achieve is to control a green laser pointer with GPIO by replacing the 2xAAA battery with a GPIO output.

PS: I've poor electronic knowledge but I'm here to learn ;)

Comment: the expansion connector is called GPIO by mistake ... only some of the pins are actual GPIO signals connected to the microcontroller ... others are power supply pins ... you could power the laser from one of the power supply pins ... do not power it from an actual GPIO pin, you could damage the microcontroller

Comment: Jstolola is correct -- this is a bit confusing.  If you mean one of the 3.3V power pins, you should be fine.   These (there are 3?) are distinct from the GPIO pins which can be turned on and off, used as inputs, etc.  Point being, not all the pins on the breakout are really GPIOs, but they tend to be referred to that way.

Answer (score 2):

A Pi GPIO can safely supply about 16 mA at 3.3V.

If the laser you are using needs 16 mA or less you should be fine.

If the laser needs more than 16 mA but less than 50 mA you could use two or three GPIO to power the device.

Comment: In other words, there is no risk to fry the laser device with a single Pi GPIO (without needing a resistor)

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the laser specs.  I use a red laser without problems. http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/red-laser

Comment: Frying the laser is not the only issue.  If you try to sink too much current from a GPIO you may fry the GPIO or worse.  That they have a maximum tolerance does not mean their amperage is controlled.

Comment: Actually if you are currently powering from a battery you should be fine.  They should be capable of providing more current than the Pi.  If the batteries don't damage the laser I don't see how the Pi GPIO could.

Comment: I don't have the laser specs.. but the fact that the laser is powered by 2xAAA batteries in series doesn't provide any clue? (obviously my laser is not a naked laser like yours, and he is embedded with some electronics to be able to be powered by 2xAAA batteries)

Comment: The batteries can provide much more than that 16 mA of current.  You could put a current limiting resistor in series with it on the GPIO (between the laser and ground).

Comment: Perhaps borrow a meter and measure the current drawn when used with the batteries.

Comment: @joan right! Everybody needs a meter, that's is such a basic tool! I go get one

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

Can I use my Rpi's GPIO pin to power a laser pointer?

***Answer***

> Well, try it or fry it.

Your cheap one dollar ”high power“ laser pointer should have a spec of 5mW.  Now let us find the current draw.  Your may find hobbyists measuring current to be in the range of < 50 mA.  But you might also read advert with spec of current draw >  300 mA.

This is a bit complicated. Perhaps you can try it, and if you fry it, then I am happy to give a postmortem. :)

(1) We cannot use Ohm's Law for a resistor: Power = Voltage x Current, because the laser diode is not a resistor, therefore does NOT obey Ohm's Law.

(2) A diode, including LED, obeys another law, ...

/ to continue (after you have fried your pi. :) ), ...

***References***

*[Amazon Green Laser Pointer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P8QBD4H)*

*[Laser pointer - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_pointer)*

*[Current Drain Of 5mw Laser Pointer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KH3Po1d3eus)*

*[Laser Diode - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_diode)*

*[How to Modify a Green Laser Pointer with an External Power Supply](https://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/83286-build-a-modified-green-laser-pointer/)*

*[Homemade Laser Pointer - pinomelean in 393,192 views](https://www.instructables.com/id/Homemade-laser-pointer/%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=ipacfLypgjs)*

***Appendices***

*Cheap Green Laser Pointer Example*

> Voltage: 3V (AAA x 2)
>
> Current < **350 mA**
>
> Power: 5 mW,
>
> Range: 500 meters
>
> Lifespan > 5000 hours
>
> Wave length: Green 532nm, Red 650nm, Blue/Violet405nm
>
> Laser characteristics: fixed focus, spot mini dia 1 mm; 15 m < 18mm

[AliEXpress 40mA Laser Diode](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/32993084789.html?gps-id=platformRecommendH5&scm=1007.18499.102167.0&scm_id=1007.18499.102167.0&scm-url=1007.18499.102167.0&pvid=51466270-81e9-406e-8ada-b6a705bd84df&_t=gps-id:platformRecommendH5,scm-url:1007.18499.102167.0,pvid:51466270-81e9-406e-8ada-b6a705bd84df&spm=a2g0n.detail-amp.moretolove.32993084789&aff_trace_key=&aff_platform=msite&m_page_id=PAGE_VIEW_IDCLIENT_ID(aefeMsite)NAV_TIMING(navigationStart))

> Power: < 5 mW
>
> Voltage: 3V~5V DC
>
> Currentnt: < ***40 mA***
>
> Lifespan: > 2000 hours
>
> Laser wavelength: 650nm (red)